# add contact in people hub from my application in winRT?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, contacts

i am using Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contact.aspx#properties.
my doubt is can i add contact to people hub from my application?,if yes then how.i am working on c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly add contacts to people app.

It has to be added to another store such as live, facebook, exchange, etc since people is a compilation of all these stores.

Comment: can i create my own store in widows 8.1 "desktop not the phone"

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [ContactPicker Contract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/hh464906).

Than you can use [ContactPickerUI.AddContact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.provider.contactpickerui.addcontact) to add contact, you cannot add a contact programmatically though.

[Contact Picker Sample Application](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Contact-Picker-App-sample-fc6677a1)